# initial value problem, mix problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

A tank initially contains 50 gallons of brine, with 30 pounds of salt in solution. Water runs into the tank at 6 gallons per minute and the well-stirred solution runs out at 5 gallons per minute. How long will it be until there are 25 pounds of salt in the tank?

I set up the differential equation as $dQ/dt=\frac{6-5Q}{(50+t)}$.

Then I used the integrating factor method to ultimately come out with $Q=\frac{t+50+C}{(t+50)^5}$. When I plug in the initial value $Q(0)=30$, I get an outrageously high number for $C$, which may be correct, but it asks how long it will take until there are 25 pounds of salt left in the tank, so logically I plug in 25 to $Q$ and solve for $t$ to find the time it will take but I keep coming out with a negative number, which makes no sense.

Any guidance is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The amount change of brine $V(t)=(6-5)t=t$;

Amount of salt in equals $0$ since there is NO SALT in;

Amount of salt out equals $\frac{5Q}{V(t)}=\frac{5Q}{(50+t)}$;

Then try $dQ/dt$ = In-Out.

Comment: can you explain that again? How did you get the amount of salt out equation?

Comment: Q/V is the density of the salt at a certain moment, and there are 5 gallons solution running out. Therefore, the total amount of salt running out will be 5Q/V. Hope it helps.

Comment: Good answer! I edited your answer to have LaTeX syntax. I know you're brand new here. Welcome to Math SE first of all! Secondly, I suggest learning LaTeX for Math SE. If you take a look around, you can see that mostly everyone here uses it. It makes equations look really pretty.

Comment: Thank you so much! I will try to learn LaTex.